# datatimepicker visualstudio casting

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to put the content of a DateTime cell into a DataTimePicker. 
It works the way I did for cells with value but not when the cells are empty.
This is the code I Did :

```
if(DateGridView1.Rows[selectedRow].Cells[2].Value.ToString() != "NULL")
            DateTimePicker1.Value = (DateTime)DateGridView1.Rows[selectedRow].Cells[2].Value;
```

When I click on empty cells this is the error shown : 
http://i.gyazo.com/273416fc2c2975fdf8902ad9bbb4caca.png

Here are the proprieties of the datatimeicker  : 
http://i.gyazo.com/0296eef11d258823904a4db0db379c04.png

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about trying with String.IsNullOrEmpty()?
If it is not NULL or Empty, check the range values. If the ranges are ok, then put the value on the control.

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(DateGridView1.Rows[selectedRow].Cells[2].Value.ToString())
{
DateTime dateTime = DateGridView1.Rows[selectedRow].Cells[2].Value;
if (dateTime > DateTimePicker1.MinValue && dateTime < DateTimePicker1.MaxValue)
{
                DateTimePicker1.Value = (DateTime)DateGridView1.Rows[selectedRow].Cells[2].Value;
}
}
```

Comment: I got this error now :
http://i.gyazo.com/217694c0d54f309520358e04fef61bd8.png
When I click on a cell with 04-01-00 00:00:00. Even thought in the proprieties linked above, i've defined the minimum and maximum date.